# mockgoose.helper.reset() does not delete database

Tags: mongodb, unit-testing, mongoose, mocha.js, mockgoose

I am creating the unit test in Node.Js using Mocha.
In this application, MongoDB is used. To mock MongoDB, I am using Mockgoose.
Following is the code

```
before(function (done) {
  mockgoose.prepareStorage().then(function () {
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://mongo.test/licenseDal', function (err) {
        var d = new Date();
        var today = d.toISOString();
        var newLic = new LicenseModel(licworking);
        newLic.createdDate = today;
        newLic.lastModifiedDate = today;
        return newLic.save().then(function (lic) {
          done(err);
        });
    });
  });
});

after(function (done) {
  mockgoose.helper.reset().then(() => {
      mongoose.connection.close().then(() => {
        done();
      });
  });
});
```

Here `mockgoose.helper.reset()` is not deleting the database.

Mockgoose version is 7.3.5

Comment: I think it will not delete the database, read this https://github.com/Mockgoose/Mockgoose#resetcallback

Comment: @SunilLulla It says it will remove all collections from a temporary store, but when I rerun test I found old data there, which means collections are not removed.

Comment: @Twix Did you find a solution for this issue?

Comment: @GuillermoGonzález No. I am manually clearing each collection in after/before helper.